# Concatenate 2 cells from Sheet1 to 1 cell Sheet2

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, concatenation

EDIT: Found the stray code that threw it off. Thanks everyone!

I've been trying to figure out the code to concatenate

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range ("B2:C2")
```

to this reference cell with " - " character as a separator:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range ("B2")
```

I've tried the following, but it says "subscript out of range":

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Cell.Value = 
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Cell.Value & 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Cell.Value
```

I've also tried this, but it only copies Sheet1.C2 to Sheet2.C2:

```
Set sourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C2")
Set targetRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")

sourceRange.Copy
targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've extra `cell`s

`Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = 
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value & 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value`

Should work.

Comment: I see no difference between what the author tried and your suggestion.  I could also be blind.  It would make sense, I attempted to ssh into the same host, I was phyiscally at just a little awhile ago.

Comment: ("B2").Cell.Value     vs   ("B2").Value  (no "CELL" in Máté suggestion)